how is this sententence divided?


俺は　死に際にこそ人たるロマンを感じる

My first reading was akin to "死に際にこそ人たるロマン" but I'm not sure it makes much sense?
俺は ロマンを感じる is I suppose "I feel the romance" Maybe it's "In one last moment I feel human worthy romance"?


俺は死に際にこそ人たるロマンを感じる
I sense the fascination of being a human at the moment of his death.


This に is a time point marker ("in/on/at"), a target marker ("against/toward") or a marker for the cause of a psychological reaction ("with/by/because of"). Either way, it adverbially modifies 感じる. (You can rephrase this sentence as 俺は人たるロマンを死に際にこそ感じる.)
人たる[輝き]{ロマン} forms a noun phrase. たる is a literary version of である.
ロマン vaguely refers to an indescribable attractiveness. Please read this: 古代のロマン ultimate dream

